# PHP - Validation radio buttons alert

Tags: javascript, php, radio-button

i have three radio buttons input within a form. i want alert box appears when user click submit without choose or answer all questions ..

this is my form ..

```
<tr>
<th> Your attendance<font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "4"    onclick="updateTotal();"/></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "3"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "2"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v1" value = "1"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th > Your grades  <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "4"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "3"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "2"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v2" value = "1"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>    
</tr>

<tr>
<th >Your self-control <font size="4" > </font></th>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "4"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "3"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "2"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>
<td>  <input type="radio" name ="v3" value = "1"    onclick="updateTotal();" /></td>    
</tr>
```

i have tried this javascript code .. but it doesn't work no alert appears

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validateform()
  {
    if(document.getElementsByName('v1').value="")
    {
      alert('Your grades is not selected');
    return false;
    }
  }
    </script>
```

Comment: where do you call `validateform()`?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Take this function, you can't use `document.getElementsByName('v1').value` on a radio group.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXajh/2/

```
function isOneChecked(name)
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByName(name);

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        if (buttons[i].checked)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;        
}
```

Comment: so update my fiddle to contain your code and we will see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `getElementsByName()` will return an array of DOM elements, you can't get value or detect if an element is checked directly from this array.  You must iterate through all elements check that at least one is checked. So something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var radiosToValidate = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'];
    var invalidRadios = [];
    for (i = 0; i < radiosToValidate.length; i++) {
        var currentRadioArray = documentGetElementsByName(radiosToValidate[i]);
        var currentRadioIsValid = false;
        for (j = 0; j < currentRadioArray.length; j++) {
            if (currentRadioArray[j].checked) {
                currentRadioIsValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (currentRadioIsValid === false) {
            invalidRadios[] = radiosToValidate[i];
        }
    }
    if (invalidRadios.length > 0) {
        alert('At least one radio button has not been selected');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I noticed a couple typos. Might try again. Or at least look at it in debugger.  The approach is correct, but I didn't try to run myself, so there could still be typos.

Answer (score -2):

Your comparison has a single `=`, not a `==`. You are assigning and testing `""`, which is falsy so your if statement will never execute.

The operator to *compare* two values is `==`.

Use this:

```
if (document.getElementsByName('v1').value== "") {
  // ...
}
```